# Tensorflow Error when restoring pretrained network - speech recognition

Tags: python, bash, tensorflow, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I'm trying to complete this tutorial of TensorFlow:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/audio_recognition
There I'm interested in creating a simple words recognition that can do speech-to-text.

However, after successfully training the network, the next step (according to the tutorial) would be to do this:

```
python tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/freeze.py \
--start_checkpoint=/tmp/speech_commands_train/conv.ckpt-18000 \
--output_file=/tmp/my_frozen_graph.pb
```

When I do this I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to get matching files on ./tmp/speech_commands_train/conv.ckpt-18000: Not found: ./tmp/speech_commands_train; No such file or directory
 [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
```

To see the whole error, I created this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/NUBSec6Q

Anyone know how I can fix this? Have been going through my directories and fiddling around, but cannot seem to come up with a solution.

Comment: I'm aware that I need the "tmp/speech_commands_train/conv.ckpt" file, however for some reason it's absent, even though the training happened on the machine I'm working on, with the directory being the TensorFlow folder

Comment: IS your training loop properly saving checkpoints?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos Found the directories, but for some reason all those maps are empty... Thinking that it might be an issue with the "clean-up time" of the tmp folder. Since I trained it and then let it for what it was for about 5 days.